# jquery mobile refire pagebeforecreate event

Tags: jquery

I have a form which is posted to the same url and the reponse is the form fields again with some new data derived from the form.

At my page I have:

```
$(document).delegate("#mypage","pagebeforecreate", function(){
     //some stuff
});
```

This is fired when the page is first accessed but not when the form returns from post.

Is there a way to refire the pagebeforecreate event?

Thank you for any input.
Andreas

Comment: Is the new data actually being inserted into the DOM, or is it just reusing the old page?  And can you post the `<form>` tag attributes you are using?

Comment: The new page is inserted correctly. No problem there. The problem is: when or better yet, where to bind a function to manipulate the NEW data AFTER the form has returned the new data. The only thing I succeeded is bind with setTimout. `$(document).delegate("#mypageid","pageinit", function() {setTimout(function(){$("#collapsible").trigger("collapse")}, 2000)});` It works fine, but it's not very pretty. I think the problem is that the pageinit event is firing to early, before all widgets are initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging the correct way to do that is use *document* and not page-id like so:

```
$(document).on("pageinit","selector",function(){
    // your code here
});
```

This will ensure that you catch the pageinit when the "page-id" is inserted to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$("#mypage").trigger("pagebeforecreate");
```

Alternatively, you could call the internal `_trigger()` method of the page widget:

```
$("#mypage").data("page")._trigger("beforecreate");
```

Comment: When should I call the trigger? The problem is that no events are firing when you load the page the second time.

Comment: @sv1jsb, ah, sorry, from your question I thought you already solved this. Did you try calling it from a `pageload` handler (only bound for the duration of the submission)?

Comment: The problem I think is that because the form is posted to the same url, the return data take the place of the old. I tried all known events: pagecreate, pageinit, pageload, pageshow and all the "before"s. No one seems to be fired when returning from post.